# How to install libxml2 and libxslt for python3

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to install `libxml2` and `libxslt` on ubuntu 16.04 using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

when finished I try to import like this:

```
import libxml2
import libxslt
```

when I use `python2` I can import without problem and when use `python3` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'xmllib2'
```

Answer (score 5):

For the first part:
    `sudo apt-get install python3-libxml2`

For libxslt, it is no longer maintained.  However, someone has ported it to work with Python3:
    https://github.com/Unidata/gempak/tree/master/extlibs/xslt/libxslt-1.1.28

It appears that it must be compiled.  Here is the documentation stating that it works with Python3:
    https://gist.github.com/novocaine/ae657bdbf0f25b81e52b

Comment: link for libxslt is no longer valid.

Comment: This one appears to still be maintained: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt